# FFMPEG logging inconsistencies whilst creating multiple clips

Tags: ffmpeg

I have noticed that the progress output that FFMPEG produces when tasked with producing multiple clips from the same source file is inconsistent. This is causing errors for my progress system in my web GUI.

The issue seems to be that when producing clips the "time=" column seems to stay at the same time. I can create the clips without any issues, i just want to know what the logging seems to be playing up when creating clips. I have tested this using -t and -to.

This is the command I am using to create the clips:

```
ffmpeg -i F:/Transcoder/processing_temp/task_00000000421/LB000001_amazon_031116105010.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -to 00:01:10.000 F:/Transcoder/processing_temp/task_00000000421/conform/s1_LB000001_amazon_031116105010.mp4 -ss 00:02:00.000 -to 00:07:00.000 F:/Transcoder/processing_temp/task_00000000421/conform/s2_LB000001_amazon_031116105010.mp4 -ss 00:07:00.000 -to 00:12:00.000 F:/Transcoder/processing_temp/task_00000000421/conform/s3_LB000001_amazon_031116105010.mp4 -ss 00:09:00.000 -to 00:11:00.000 F:/Transcoder/processing_temp/task_00000000421/conform/s4_LB000001_amazon_031116105010.mp4 2> F:/Transcoder/logs/transcode_logs/c_00000000421.txt
```

Here are some examples:

It its fine but on producing the final clip it seems to just output this:

```
frame= 1500 fps= 16 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed=3.23x    
frame= 1500 fps= 16 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed=3.22x    
frame= 1500 fps= 16 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed= 3.2x    
frame= 1500 fps= 16 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed=3.18x    
frame= 1500 fps= 16 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed=3.16x    
frame= 1500 fps= 16 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed=3.15x    
frame= 1500 fps= 16 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed=3.13x    
frame= 1500 fps= 16 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed=3.11x    
frame= 1500 fps= 15 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 q=28.0 size=    3057kB time=00:04:59.94 bitrate=  83.5kbits/s speed= 3.1x    
frame= 1500 fps= 15 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 q=-1.0 q=-1.0 size=    3173kB time=00:05:00.01 bitrate=  86.6kbits/s speed=3.08x
```

It does this for 100 lines before `time=00:05:00.000` (end of the requested clip) is reached and the task ends.

Compare this output with a standard transcode and you can see that time= iterates as you would expect.

Here is an example:

```
frame=16519 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   54023kB time=00:11:01.02 bitrate= 669.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.42x    
frame=16628 fps=211 q=28.0 size=   54290kB time=00:11:05.39 bitrate= 668.4kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.42x    
frame=16753 fps=211 q=28.0 size=   54602kB time=00:11:10.37 bitrate= 667.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.43x    
frame=16871 fps=211 q=28.0 size=   54915kB time=00:11:15.10 bitrate= 666.4kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.44x    
frame=16963 fps=211 q=28.0 size=   55293kB time=00:11:18.79 bitrate= 667.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.43x    
frame=17062 fps=211 q=25.0 size=   55653kB time=00:11:22.74 bitrate= 667.8kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.43x    
frame=17174 fps=211 q=28.0 size=   56007kB time=00:11:27.24 bitrate= 667.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.43x    
frame=17276 fps=211 q=28.0 size=   56347kB time=00:11:31.34 bitrate= 667.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.43x    
frame=17357 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   56763kB time=00:11:34.56 bitrate= 669.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.42x    
frame=17458 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   57180kB time=00:11:38.59 bitrate= 670.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.41x    
frame=17552 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   57541kB time=00:11:42.34 bitrate= 671.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.41x    
frame=17659 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   57926kB time=00:11:46.61 bitrate= 671.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.41x    
frame=17756 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   58253kB time=00:11:50.51 bitrate= 671.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.41x    
frame=17903 fps=211 q=28.0 size=   58566kB time=00:11:56.40 bitrate= 669.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.43x    
frame=17983 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   59032kB time=00:11:59.58 bitrate= 672.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.41x    
frame=18051 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   59517kB time=00:12:02.31 bitrate= 675.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.39x    
frame=18135 fps=210 q=28.0 size=   59944kB time=00:12:05.64 bitrate= 676.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.38x    
frame=18231 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   60307kB time=00:12:09.52 bitrate= 677.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.38x    
frame=18314 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   60589kB time=00:12:12.85 bitrate= 677.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.37x    
frame=18405 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   60998kB time=00:12:16.48 bitrate= 678.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.36x    
frame=18490 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   61401kB time=00:12:19.85 bitrate= 679.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.35x    
frame=18579 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   61668kB time=00:12:23.43 bitrate= 679.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.35x    
frame=18650 fps=208 q=28.0 size=   62048kB time=00:12:26.27 bitrate= 681.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.33x    
frame=18751 fps=208 q=28.0 size=   62446kB time=00:12:30.32 bitrate= 681.8kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.33x    
frame=18855 fps=208 q=28.0 size=   62802kB time=00:12:34.44 bitrate= 681.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.33x    
frame=18972 fps=208 q=28.0 size=   63088kB time=00:12:39.18 bitrate= 680.8kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.34x    
frame=19091 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   63385kB time=00:12:43.93 bitrate= 679.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.34x    
frame=19209 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   63709kB time=00:12:48.65 bitrate= 679.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.35x    
frame=19317 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   63979kB time=00:12:52.94 bitrate= 678.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.35x    
frame=19417 fps=209 q=28.0 size=   64387kB time=00:12:56.97 bitrate= 678.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.35x    
frame=19502 fps=208 q=-1.0 Lsize=   65344kB time=00:13:00.08 bitrate= 686.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=8.33x
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: When `ss` is applied after the input name, FFmpeg decodes all frames upto that inpoint and discards them. During this seek operation, the time indicator will not change.

Comment: So does that mean I have to include the -i and source file string after every -ss?

Comment: So doing this the time= progresses as you would expect it to, however all the clips are now starting at the first -ss in point.